# How to check if filters have been applyed in template?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm working on an admin-generator module. I'd like to hide the item-list until the user has used the filters. So I'd like to check, if the filter-form has been sent.

Is there any var I can check for this in the `indexSuccess.php` Template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are stored inside the session when the user submit them.

So, in your template, you can access defined filter by calling the session. If you don't have defaults filter, it will return an empty array (might be `sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator` if you use output protection).

If you module name is `car` for example, you can get filters inside your template using:

```
$filters = $sf_user->getAttribute('car.filters', null, 'admin_module');
```

And if you use output protection, you can do:

```
$filters = sfOutputEscaper::unescape($sf_user->getAttribute('car.filters', null, 'admin_module'));
```

If you do not have filters, you will get something like this with a `var_dump` (with the first solution):

```
object(sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator)[181]
  private 'count' => int 0
  protected 'value' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'escapingMethod' => string 'esc_specialchars' (length=16)
```

And with the second:

```
array
  empty
```

For example, if you have some filters define, you will get :

```
array
  'model' => 
    array
      'text' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'updated_at' => 
    array
      'from' => null
      'to' => null
  'created_at' => 
    array
      'from' => null
      'to' => null
```